# How to use API GET request on HTML page with javascript / ajax to retrieve data?

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, api, get

I am following this documentation: https://docs.oracle.com/cloud/latest/marketingcs_gs/OMCAC/DeterminingBaseURL.html

Using basic authentication.

I have already determined the base URL, so I am using the base URL directly in the code.

I am not 100% if i need authorization code or not (not sure, how i will get it) so i am not using this in my code: https://docs.oracle.com/cloud/latest/marketingcs_gs/OMCAC/Authentication_Basic.html

I am trying to get a list of emails by a simple GET request like here: https://docs.oracle.com/cloud/latest/marketingcs_gs/OMCAC/api-application-2.0-emails.html

So far, I have created this code but I do not see any success?  why? is there any issue with my code? can anyone help please?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            var username = "MYUSERNAME";
            var password = "MYPASSWORD";

            function make_base_auth(user, password) {
                var tok = user + ':' + password;
                var hash = btoa(tok);
                return "Basic " + hash;
            }

            var url1 = 'https://BASEURL.com/api/REST/2.0/assets/emails';

            $.ajax
                ({
                    type: "GET",
                    url: url1,
                    dataType: 'jsonp',
                    cache: false,
                    //contentType: 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
                    headers: {                        
                        'Accept': 'text/html',
                        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                        'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
                        'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '* ',
                        'Access-Control - Allow - Headers': 'Origin, X-Requested - With, Content-Type, Accept'
                    },
                    //async: false,
                    //data: '{}',
                    beforeSend: function (xhr) {
                        xhr.setRequestHeader('Authorization', make_base_auth(username, password));
                    },
                    error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                        alert(textStatus, errorThrown);
                        console.log(errorThrown);
                    },
                    success: function (result) {
                        console.log(result);
                        alert('success - this is working');
                    }
                    //success: function (jsondata) {
                    //    console.log(status);
                    //}
                });

        });

    </script>
</head>
<body>





</body>
</html>
```

**I am getting CORP error in the log. Based on the documentation that I have provided, do I need to pass 'Authorization' in the header? If yes, how can i get the authorization code?**

**How to report the CORP error?**

**The alert box only says "error".**

[image: Console log in Chrome]

Comment: Alert done is outside the asynchronous function, so it gets called no matter what, it does not provide any information about the result of the AJAX call. Can you provide a handler for `fail` and `done` to see what goes wrong? You can also check the browser console.

Comment: Hi @RaulSauco I have updated the code and provided more info on the error. Please see my updated post / code / questions above.

Answer (score 2):

Please check this [codepen](https://codepen.io/chin-ngh/pen/RmEEqM) (I made it with your code) and replace it with your real requesting url.

When you click on the button, you will see the url is requested successfully as following image

[image]

Make sure you use `dataType: 'jsonp'` for cross-site requesting.

Moreover, in your code, there is a redudant single quote at the end of line `success: function (result) {'`, please remove it.

For the `alert("done")`, it is always executed because it's not part of async process. it's executed right after the ajax command triggered.

Comment: Thank you @chiến-nghê for taking time to test this for me, it is helpful what you pointed out.  I updated the code, added ERROR alert and getting CORP error in the log. I am also not sure if I need to send 'Authorization' in header or not. I have shared the documentation that I am following, could you please confirm, if i have to send authorization code, how to get one? And how to resolve CORP error?

Comment: In order to check whether your basic authentication (username/password) is correct. Please use some tools like Postman to do. For the CORS warning, maybe Oracle's API doesn't allow cross-site requesting, hence, you need to make request to Oracle API from your server instead of client browser.

Comment: Hi Chen i did use postman and I am able to authenticate and get a response. I see an authentication code being generated. I tried copying all the headers as postman like the request was coming from postman (including authentication code), I stop getting COPS error but then I am getting unauthorized 401 error. I have triple checked all credentials, all works outside the ajax code. How can i troubleshoot?